# Google+ photo comments error: "Sorry, we are temporarily unable to post your comment. Please try again in a few minutes."

Tags: google-plus

I keep getting this error in Google+ every time I post a comment on a photo that is privately shared with me. What am I doing wrong?

Chrome 38 through Chrome 44, with or without with AdBlock or [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock/epcnnfbjfcgphgdmggkamkmgojdagdnn).

I've reported the issue in [Chromium's Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514453).

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ Probably nothing. A temporary glitch, perhaps? Have you tried with a different browser? Have you tried with AdBlock off? What about other extensions? It's been most of a day since you posted this. Is it still happening?

Comment: It's been happening for the past weeks... always Chrome; I've disabled Adblock, commenting worked, then enabled it again, and commenting still worked. Hate transient errors.